# Can't update view/function 'cte' because it contains aggregates, when calculating times over 24 hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I have a datatable `alarms` with columns, two of which are: `tmStartTime` and `tmEndtime`. I want to calculate the total active time `tmTotals` in hours, this can be over 24 hours. So for example `24:00:04`

my datatable `Alarms` (I used data type `TIME`here which worked fine for times less than 24 hour):

```
tmStarttime               tmEndTime                 tmTotals
--------------------------------------------------------------
2018-12-03 00:00:19.257   2018-12-04 00:00:23.288   00:00:04  (is actually 24:00:04)
2018-12-03 23:59:16.817   2018-12-04 00:01:42.942   00:02:26
2018-12-03 23:59:45.005   2018-12-04 00:07:03.650   00:07:18
2018-12-03 23:11:57.645   2018-12-04 00:07:16.785   00:55:19
2018-12-04 00:03:52.086   2018-12-04 00:07:37.991   00:03:45
2018-12-04 00:07:16.787   2018-12-04 00:08:14.302   00:00:57
2018-12-04 00:08:30.430   2018-12-04 00:08:34.480   00:00:04
```

With times over 24 hours I found I should do:

```
UPDATE Messages_History
SET tmTotals
= right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 3600 )),2) + ':'
+ right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 60 ) % 60 ),2) + ':'
+ right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) %60 )),2)
```

Here I got the error:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.
```

I then found I should do:

```
    WITH cte

    AS (SELECT new_tmTotals 
    = right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 3600 )),2) + ':'
    + right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 60 ) % 60 ),2) + ':'
    + right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) %60 )),2), tmTotals
    FROM Messages_History
    GROUP BY tmTotals)

    UPDATE cte
    SET tmTotals = new_tmTotals
```

When executing the Stored Procedure I got the error:

```
Cannot update the view or function 'cte' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.
```

I'm a bit lost what I have to do now, I found something about deleting duplicate rows, but I need to keep duplicates.

Comment: Change your datatype. Time is the wrong datatype here as you have discovered. In addition, your choice is probably based on a desire to simplify your display logic because you have confused "value" with "format". The calculation of hours is done with datediff in the units of precision you desire. Presumably seconds (not hours as you state) since that is what you display. Formatting that should be left to the consumer of the data. And one last comment - show the desired result. I don't think you need to sum at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you may try updating using a join:

```
UPDATE mh1
SET tmTotals = mh2.new_tmTotals
FROM Messages_History mh1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        tmTotals,
           RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(9),
           (sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 3600 )),2) + ':' +
           RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 60 ) % 60 ),2) + ':' +
           RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) %60 )),2) AS new_tmTotals
    FROM Messages_History
    GROUP BY tmTotals
) mh2
    ON mh1.tmTotals = mh2.tmTotals;
```

The basic issue with the error is that you are trying to update a derived (aggregated) table, and SQL Server is refusing to decide how the original underlying table should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Primary` or `Unique` key to the Table to get resolved from this issue. And then use below one...

```
WITH cte

AS (SELECT UniqueID 'Uniq_ID',new_tmTotals = right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 3600 )),2) + ':'
+ right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) / 60 ) % 60 ),2) + ':'
+ right ('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,tmStartTime,tmEndTime)) %60 )),2), tmTotals
FROM Messages_History
GROUP BY tmTotals)

UPDATE cte
SET tmTotals = new_tmTotals
WHERE UniqueID = Uniq_ID
```